# Global solution to $y'(t) + y^2 = f(t)$ on interval [a,b] when f is smooth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that a solution to the equation $$y'(t) + y^2(t) = f(t)$$ with initial condition $y(a) =0$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$, where $f$ is a smooth function on $[a,b]$. Since I can write this as $$y' = - y^2 +f$$ and the function $$g(t,x) = -x^2 +f(t)$$ is Locally Lipschitz in $x$ uniformly in $t$ I can at least show that there exists a solution for some small interval $[0,\varepsilon]$. Now I would like to show that the solution exists on the whole interval $[a,b]$. I have looked for some suitable theorem but I haven't found any.

Does anyone kno how this could be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f\equiv-c^2$ you get
$$
\frac{y'}{y^2+c^2}=-1 \iff \frac{(y/c)'}{1+(y/c)^2}=-c\implies y(t)=c·\tan(D-ct)
$$
and for $y(a)=0$ one gets $D=ca$. Now one can make $c$ large enough, $c(b−a)>\frac π2$, that the first pole singularity of the tangent falls inside the interval, thus invalidating the claim.

Comment: What pole are you talking about?

Comment: The pole singularity at $c(t-a)=\frac\pi2$ of the tangens function. You only need $c$ large enough to have $c(b-a)>\frac\pi2$ to get a counter-example.